# Watch attribute change of value (2-way-databinding) in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to do 2-way-data-binding to watch DOM attribute value.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <annotations>
      
      <!-- Need to watch x value. <rect> wil be manipulated from <annotations> to hide complexity -->
      <rect :x="x" class="box" slot="annotation" y="10" width="100" height="100"></rect>
      
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
    </annotations>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    'annotations': () => import('./components/Annotator')
  },
  data () {
    return {
      x: 10
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to watch it but it doesn't work

```
watch: {
    x (val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
  }
```

Also try to use [sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) (hopefully it do some magic) but still same

```
<rect :x.sync="x" class="box" slot="annotation" y="10" width="100" height="100"></rect>
```

Note: `<rect>` is [svg element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect)

[image: Edit Watch attribute on slot]

Comment: What is the `rect` component doing?

Comment: Actually the `rect` is not component, its [svg element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect). I want to draw `rect` above `img` using `svg element` and manipulate the `svg element` inside `annotations` component. For full code, you can click `sandbox` button.

Answer (score 1):

[The `.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) relies on the component emitting `update` events. A plain SVG is not going to be able to do that. Only a Vue component can.

It looks like your `annotations` component is what modifies `x` in the SVG. That is what you should be binding your `x` variable to, and when it changes values, the component should emit events.

Comment: I also think to pass it on event emitter. However, if there is many element (for example 100 rect, ellipse, and/or canvas) is that still possible to watch individual xValue element change on parent?

Comment: You have to keep track of them somewhere. You may have an array of them. I don't have a very good idea of how your program should work.